# Is energy destroyed in electron-hole pair annihilation?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In the electron-hole recombination process, the electron passes from the conduction band to the valence band, in this process the other leaves a gap in the conduction band and fills the gap in the valence band. And this is called electron-hole pair annihilation? Or is everything destroyed?

Comment: What do you mean by everything being destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

> [Electron-hole recombination](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/559475/electron-recombination)

> The process in which an electron, which has been excited from the valence band to the conduction band of a semiconductor, falls back into an empty state in the valence band, which is known as a hole. [See Band theory of solids](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/band.html)

> Light with photon energies greater than the band gap can be absorbed by the crystal, exciting electrons from the filled valence band to the empty conduction band The state in which an electron is removed from the filled valence band is known as a hole. It is analogous to a bubble in a liquid. The hole can be thought of as being mobile and having positive charge. The excited electrons and holes rapidly lose energy (in about $10^{-12}$ s) by the excitation of lattice phonons (vibrational quanta). The excited electrons fall to near the bottom of the conduction band, and the holes rise to near the top of the valence band, and then on a much longer time scale (of $10^{-9}$ to $10^{-6}$ s) the electron drops across the energy gap into the empty state represented by the hole. This is known as electron-hole recombination. An energy approximately equal to the band gap is released in the process. Electron-hole recombination is radiative if the released energy is light and nonradiative if it is heat.

Everything is not destroyed as energy is released as either photons or phonons.